# Up to isometry, how many product metrics are there?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, products

Given two metric spaces $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$, you can form a [product metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_metric) on the space $X \times Y$ by letting your metric be the $p$-product-metric for any $p \in [1,\infty)$ or the sup-metric for $p \to \infty$. But,

1. Do each of these metrics for $p \in [1,\infty]$ necessarily define isometric metric spaces? <strike>The [blurb on Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_metric) only says this is true for Euclidian spaces</strike><sup>[*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635368/up-to-isometry-how-many-product-metrics-are-there?noredirect=1#comment7475041_3635368)</sup>.
2. What other metrics $d$ can we define on $X \times Y$ that are distinct up to isometry from these $p$-product metrics? Note that when defining a product metric $d$ on $X \times Y$, we should require that the restrictions of $d$ to $X$ and $Y$ make sense. Ie that $d|_{X\times\{y\}} = d_X$ for all $y \in Y$ and $d|_{\{x\}\times Y} = d_Y$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: $d_p((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))$ is just $\lVert (d_X(x_1,x_2), d_Y(y_1,y_2))\rVert_p$, where $\lVert \bullet\rVert_p$ is the usual $p$-norm on $\Bbb R^2$. Therefore, as soon as the image sets of $d_X$ and $d_Y$ contain sufficently large subsets of $\Bbb R$, no two $(X\times Y,d_p)$ will be isometric (since no two $(\Bbb R^2,\lVert \bullet\rVert_p)$ are isometric). However, they will be bi-Lipschitz equivalent, and so will be any similar construction with a norm on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Your citation of that Wikipedia link does not match what it actually says: those metrics for different values of $p \in [1,\infty]$ define topologically equivalent metrics (and even more, they define biLipschitz equivalent metrics), but they do *not* define isometric metrics.